# Can Not increase token lifetime via custom policy in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I tried many times to update token lifetime. When I use users flows, I can update token life time without any problem. On the other hand, doing the same thing in custom policy is not working.

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="token_lifetime_secs">3600</Item>
            <Item Key="id_token_lifetime_secs">3600</Item>
            <Item Key="refresh_token_lifetime_secs">1209600</Item>
            <!--<Item Key="rolling_refresh_token_lifetime_secs">7776000</Item>-->
            <Item Key="allow_infinite_rolling_refresh_token">true</Item>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="ClientId">app id </Item>
            <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">app object id</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
          </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Any ideas?

I tried many times to update token lifetime. When I use users flows, I can update token life time without any problem. On the other hand, doing the same thing in custom policy is not working. The access token life time is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because this metadata should be in a JwtIssuer technical profile, not AAD-Common.